# While loop appears broken. Has something to do with csv reader

Tags: python, file-io, while-loop

So, this is extremely strange. I'm writing a script to take in a couple csv files and compare values. Essentially, as I iterate through one file, I'm moving an index counter.

This is the while loop I'm using to move the counter:

```
futuresCode = futures[futures_row]['futures_code']
corCode = row[cor_wc_code]    
while(futuresCode < corCode):
                print `futures_row`+' and Futures code: '+`futures[futures_row]['futures_code']`
                futures_row += 1
                futuresCode = futures[futures_row]['futures_code']
                corCode = row[cor_wc_code]
```

Where the futuresCode and corCode are the internal codes I'm comparing from the CSV folder.

This code works for about the first 13 entries in futures[], however after that it never enters the while loop, even though futuresCode remains at 99 while corCode continues to like 194 before reaching the end of the file.

Is there some weird quirk to the python while loop that I don't know?

Comment: What makes you think that "it never enters the while loop"?  What makes you think that "futuresCode remains at 99 while corCode continues to like 194"?

Comment: Are `futuresCode` and `corCode` integers, or strings? Strings are lexicographically ordered, so "194" is less than "99".

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I was convinced that the programming language was doing it wrong... Do you know how many times I was right? Guess..

Comment: It would be best if you could submit a **complete**, **short** program that demonstrate the error you are seeing. Reduce your failing program to the smallest possible program that still fails. Copy-paste that entire, short program into your question. For more information about this technique, visit http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: Best if you can provide a complete set of code, inputs and outputs.  If you can't then I suggest you add one line at the bottom of your while loop: `print futuresCode, type(futuresCode), corCode, type(corCode), bool(futuresCode < corCode)`.  That should tell you what's going on.

Comment: @CalebJ, one of the tactics that can help you grow your abilities as a developer it to understand what your code is doing at a lower level.  Learn to use a debugger, examine values of individual variables, etc. -- trace through your code and see what it is actually doing.  You could have solved this problem for yourself.  It's OK to ask for help, but developers face riddles analogous to what you were stuck on all the time -- you will want to have the tools and knowledge to solve your own riddles!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> if '194'<'99':
...   print 'gotcha'
...
gotcha
```

To coerce strings to int:

```
if int('194')<int('99'):
```

Comment: Alright, that worked. It's so weird that print statements will turn an int into a string.

Comment: No, that's not why it's happening. When you read from a file, everything is a string. It's up to you to change it to an int after you read from a file.

Comment: @CalebJ -- Joe is right. After all, Python doesn't have a clue what's inside the file you're reading. It could be letters, numbers, characters, funny emoticons, etc... So to be safe, it defaults to returning a string every time, since it's the most inclusive type. Python won't try and guess that you mean to return a number, since that path leads to ambiguity. (The same thing applies to raw_input)